# How To Upload Files on GitHub

Tags: file-upload, github

I have recently downloaded `GitHub` and created a repository on it. I am trying to upload an `Objective C` project in it. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 27):

I didn't find the above answers sufficiently explicit, and it took me some time to figure it out for myself. The most useful page I found was:
http://www.lockergnome.com/web/2011/12/13/how-to-use-github-to-contribute-to-open-source-projects/

I'm on a Unix box, using the command line. I expect this will all work on a Mac command line. (Mac or Window GUI looks to be available at desktop.github.com but I haven't tested this, and don't know how transferable this will be to the GUI.)

Step 1: Create a Github account
Step 2: Create a new repository, typically with a README and LICENCE file created in the process.
Step 3: Install "git" software. 
(Links in answers above and online help at github should suffice to do these steps, so I don't provide detailed instructions.)
Step 4: Tell git who you are:

```
git config --global user.name "<NAME>"
git config --global user.email "<email>"
```

I think the e-mail must be one of the addresses you have associated with the github account. I used the same name as I used in github, but I think (not sure) that this is not required. Optionally you can add caching of credentials, so you don't need to type in your github account name and password so often. https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Create and navigate to some top level working directory:

```
mkdir <working>
cd <working>
```

Import the nearly empty repository from github:

```
git clone https://github.com/<user>/<repository>
```

This might ask for credentials (if github repository is not 'public'.)
Move to directory, and see what we've done:

```
cd <repository>
ls -a
git remote -v
```

(The 'ls' and 'git remote' commands are optional, they just show you stuff)
Copy the 10000 files and millions of lines of code that you want to put in the repository:

```
cp -R <path>/src .
git status -s
```

(assuming everything you want is under a directory named "src".) (The second command again is optional and just shows you stuff)

Add all the files you just copied to git, and optionally admire the the results:

```
git add src
git status -s
```

Commit all the changes:

```
git commit -m "<commit comment>"
```

Push the changes

```
git push origin master
```

"Origin" is an alias for your github repository which was automatically set up by the "git clone" command. "master" is the branch you are pushing to. Go look at github in your browser and you should see all the files have been added.

Optionally remove the directory you did all this in, to reclaim disk space:

```
cd ..
rm -r <working>
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question.  It should be the best answer.

Comment: Excellent post!

Answer (score 20):

Well, there really is a lot to this. I'm assuming you have an account on http://github.com/. If not, go get one.

After that, you really can just follow their guide, its very simple and easy and the explanation is much more clear than mine: http://help.github.com/ >> http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/

To answer your specific question: You upload files to github through the `git push` command after you have added your files you needed through `git add 'files'` and commmited them `git commit -m "my commit messsage"`

Comment: Hi Justin, I have an account on GitHub and created a repository. Where exactly do I type the "git push" command ? Thanks ...

Comment: @CaiGengyang: You do that in the Git Bash or the native system console, depending upon which one you chose while installing Git. Commenting after a gap of more than one year, just to help others who might come searching here.

Answer (score 11):

You need to create a git repo locally, add your project files to that repo, commit them to the local repo, and then sync that repo to your repo on github.  You can find good instructions on how to do the latter bit [on github](http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/), and the former should be easy to do with the software you've downloaded.

Answer (score 8):

To upload files to your repo without using the command-line, simply type this after your repository name in the browser:

https://github.com/yourname/yourrepositoryname**/upload/master**

and then drag and drop your files.(provided you are on github and the repository has been created beforehand)

Answer (score 7):

Here are the steps (in-short), since I don't know what exactly you have done:
1. Download and install Git on your system: http://git-scm.com/downloads
2. Using the Git Bash (a command prompt for Git) or your system's native command prompt, set up a local git repository.
3. Use the same console to checkout, commit, push, etc. the files on the Git.

Hope this helps to those who come searching here.

Answer (score 7):

if you're on windows:

http://windows.github.com/

otherwise:
http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to upload a folder or a file to Github

1- Create a repository on the Github

2- make: git remote add origin "Your Link" as it is described on the Github

3- Then use git push -u origin master.

4- You have to enter your username and Password.

5- After the authentication, the transfer will start

Answer (score 0):

If I follow these steps:

1- Create a repository on the Github

2- make: git remote add origin "Your Link" as it is described on the Github
I get an error "error: remote origin already exists."