# Is it possible to upload files to a git-hub account / repo with out downloading the application?

Tags: javascript, github

I need to upload a file to my repo.

Can I do this using, just the web interface?

Here is a related question w/ no answer, just link outs.

[How To Upload Files on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577968/how-to-upload-files-on-github)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can... You can simply create a new file inside of a repo.

[image: git new file]

EDIT: According to [this blog post](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads), there is no way to directly upload files anymore. This feature was deprecated as of December 2012.

Comment: I need to upload a file.  The create button seems to just let you type text into an editor.