# How to Commits changes from the local computer to a remote repository on the server using Git

Tags: git, github

hello i have a folder with the application on the computer and I have to put it to a remote repository on the server and run on the server (so that all developers see the change) using git.
How to do it.
I will add that on your computer and the server is installed git.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using GitHub to host your repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use git push for that.

```
git add "directory/fileName"
git commit -m "your comment here"    
git push origin master
```

For more detailed info:

[How To Upload Files on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577968/how-to-upload-files-on-github)

Comment: https://www.linux.com/learn/how-run-your-own-git-server hope this solves your problem.

Comment: You can accept the answer if your problem has been solved. :) @Kaker